# jQuery 0.value is null or not an object doesn't make sense to me

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following:

```
$('#TopicRowKey')[0].value,
```

When I check using IE debugger and do a watch on the object I see it has a value. But when the script runs it comes up with a message saying: 0.value is null or not an object

Can someone explain if it's related to the [0]. I don't really understand with jQuery what the [0] is for.

```
            <select  id="Topic" name="TopicRowKey">
                    <option value="01">aa</option>
                    <option value="02">bb</option>
            </select>
```

- Note that I realized one thing that's wrong. My id name is not correct :-(  I looked at this for so long and didn't see it in the code.

Comment: What kind of element is #TopicRowKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery returns an array-like object.

This means it is an object that can be traversed as if it was an array.

When you do $("#myId")[0], it returns the actual element of the page.

That is, your jQuery sintax is correct. Perhaps this element does not support a value (like a div, for example), or you're making a mistake somewhere else. You'll have to provide full code for us to see what is actually wrong.

Here is a fiddle with a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/SW5Hz/

**Edit:**

You're searching for the wrong id. It should be

```
$("#Topic")[0].value;
```

or

```
$("#Topic").val();
```

The # are meant for id only. If you want to search for name, do:

```
$("[name='TopicRowKey']")[0].value;
```

or

```
$("[name='TopicRowKey']").first().val();
```

Comment: Thank you Andre. Now it looks so obvious. Before I didn't see what was wrong even after looking for a long time. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Observe that this occurs in IE when the element with ID TopicRowKey does not actually exist in the document. Make sure that your given element exists at the time you run your code and actually has an ID attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Edited:
You should try `$('#TopicRowKey').val(),`

[0] is for the index.

Comment: Using [0] means you're dealing directly with an element (specifically the first element of the jQuery selection, as a jQuery selection is always an array), not a jQuery object, so .val() (a jQuery method) won't work. Depending on what type of element #TopicRowKey is, the original posted code or just $('#TopicRowKey').val() -- without the [0] -- should work.

Comment: I just tried and now get the message:  '0' is null or not an object   Does it matter that the contents of TopicRowKey is a string looking like "01" and not a number?

Comment: I assume it is something like a text input.

Comment: @Rwl, i stand corrected. Thanks for pointing that out, editing my answer accordingly.

Comment: @RwL - It's now working (almost). Actually I have a json call and am using: { TopicRowKey: $('#TopicRowKey').val(), SubTopicID: $('#SubTopicID').val() }, What I find is that the second element SubTopicID is getting populated and sent to my controller but not the first. I will look into this. This seems to be another issue. Thank you all for your help.